# Alternative to assertions in DB2

Tags: sql, transactions, db2, assertions

Using DB2, I am trying to realize a constraint effecting more than one table i.e. an assertion.
Let me make a simple example:

Assume that there are two tables "person" and "dog":

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(255)
)

CREATE TABLE dog(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(255), 
    owner INT NOT NULL REFERENCES person
)
```

and that you want to ensure that every person owns **exactly** 2 dogs.
Lets insert 2 people and their dogs for that example:

```
-- Insert Paul and his two dogs
INSERT INTO person VALUES (1, 'Paul')
INSERT INTO dog VALUES (1, 'Elmo', 1)
INSERT INTO dog VALUES (2, 'Ripper', 1)

-- Insert Amy and only one dog
INSERT INTO person VALUES (2, 'Amy')
INSERT INTO dog VALUES (3, 'Onko', 2)
```

Of course I can find out the ids of persons who do not have exactly two dogs with the following statement:

```
SELECT person.id
FROM person 
    LEFT JOIN dog ON person.id = dog.owner 
GROUP BY person.id 
HAVING COUNT(dog.id) <> 2

-- | id |
-- ------
-- |  2 |
```

If every person owns exactly two dogs this result set must of course be empty. To ensure this, one might want to create an assertion which is not available in DB2. Creating a trigger seems to be an alternative for that:
(Let's first clear the tables before creating the trigger)

```
DELETE FROM dog
DELETE FROM person

CREATE TRIGGER person_has_two_dogs_1
AFTER INSERT ON person
FOR EACH STATEMENT
WHEN (
    EXISTS (SELECT person.id FROM person LEFT JOIN dog ON person.id = dog.owner GROUP BY person.id HAVING COUNT(dog.id) IS NULL OR COUNT(dog.id) <> 2)
)
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '23506' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'A person does not own exactly 2 dogs'
```

(to be complete this trigger must of course also be created for delete on person and insert/update/delete on dog)

The problem is that now I cannot insert any persons anymore because a newly inserted person has of course no dogs. Intuitionally, I would solve that problem by using a transaction i.e. ask the DBMS to shut down all constrains for a second to let me insert a new person **and** his dogs and check the constrains afterwards.

Unfortunatly, a trigger is not considered as a constraint in DB2 and is therefore not effected by transactions. I tried this over quite a lot of ways:

Via the interactive shell by setting auto-commit off

```
UPDATE COMMAND OPTIONS USING c OFF
```

Via the command line by executing a script file having auto-commit deactivated:

```
db2 +c -tvf filename
```

Via JDBC and auto-commit off

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false)
```

Everything was of course fruitless because a trigger is not considered as a constraint and is therefore not turned off during a transaction.

Does anyone know a workaround to implement such an assertion in DB2 or to turn of the triggers for a series of commands?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rethink your data structure. For your simple example, have the owner who reference the dog instead of the dog referencing it's owner.

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(255),
    dog1 INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dog,
    dog2 INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dog
)

CREATE TABLE dog(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(255)
)
```

you can also add a constraint, that `dog1<>dog2`. Now you need to add the dogs first and then the owner. You might get stray dogs though.

However, with this setup you can create a view that displays both dogs and the owner and you might be able to add records through the view. You might be able to place more constraints on the tables to achieve your goals, but do you want to get that complicated?

Actually, when I think again about it, then lets get back to simple.

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(255),
    dogname1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    dogname2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Hey, that's a good suggestion. But I'm actually looking for a more general solution. E.g. substitute "dog" with "bill" with an attribute "amount" and you want to ensure that the sum of all bills does not exceed a certain value.

Comment: As long as you go for upper limits only, you should be fine with a trigger. When you go with lower limits, then you are in trouble. My suggestion for complex constraints is to offload that kind of validation into program logic outside of the database and let the app decide whether the data is valid or not.

Comment: I would normally agree with you. But at least in theory, relational database systems should be able to maintain data consistency on their own. Thats why the `CREATE ASSERTION` statement is part of the SQL standard since SQL92. I must admit that my case is a bit theoretical but I am really hoping to find a pure database solution to the problem.

Comment: The question is what is the best tool for a job and IMHO a relational database is not the best fit for the most complex business rules.